# How do linkers decide what parts of libraries to include?

Tags: c, linker

Assume library A has a() and b(). If I link my program B with A and call a(), does b() get included in the binary? Does the compiler see if any function in the program call b() (perhaps a() calls b() or another lib calls b())? If so, how does the compiler get this information? If not, isn't this a big waste of final compile size if I'm linking to a big library but only using a minor feature?

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [link-time optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-time_optimization). This is necessarily vendor dependent. It will also depend how you build your binaries. MS compilers (2005 onwards at least) provide something called [Function Level Linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa71f43(VS.80).aspx) -- which is another way of stripping symbols you don't need. [This](https://ribosome.helixcommunity.org/2005/devdocs/FuncLevelLinking) post explains how the same can be achieved with GCC (this is old, GCC must've moved on but the content is relevant to your question).

Also take a look at the [LLVM](http://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html#phase3) implementation (and the examples section).

I suggest you also take a look at [Linkers and Loaders](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558604960) by John Levine -- an excellent read.

Comment: Generally, Link-time Optimization addresses much more than removing unreferenced objects and functions - LTO generally refers to technology that can optimize generated code at link time - things such as inlining functions or recognizing that pointers are not aliasing objects.

Comment: @Michael Burr: Correct. But that's one place to look for. Also, this is why I quoted so many references.

Comment: Sure - I didn't mean to imply there was anything wrong with the answer - just pointing out that LTO generally is much more than function level linking.

Answer (score 7):

It depends.

If the library is a shared object or DLL, then everything in the library is loaded, but at run time. The cost in extra memory is (hopefully) offset by sharing the library (really, the code pages) between all the processes in memory that use that library. This is a big win for something like `libc`.so, less so for `myreallyobscurelibrary.so`. But you probably aren't asking about shared objects, really.

Static libraries are a simply a collection of individual object files, each the result of a separate compilation (or assembly), and possibly not even written in the same source language. Each object file has a number of exported symbols, and almost always a number of imported symbols.

The linker's job is to create a finished executable that has no remaining undefined imported symbols. (I'm lying, of course, if dynamic linking is allowed, but bear with me.) To do that, it starts with the modules named explicitly on the link command line (and possibly implicitly in its configuration) and assumes that any module named explicitly must be part of the finished executable. It then attempts to find definitions for all of the undefined symbols.

Usually, the named object modules expect to get symbols from some library such as `libc.a`.

In your example, you have a single module that calls the function `a()`, which will result in the linker looking for module that exports `a()`.

You say that the library named A (on unix, probably `libA.a`) offers `a()` and `b()`, but you don't specify how. You implied that `a()` and `b()` do not call each other, which I will assume.

If `libA.a` was built from `a.o` and `b.o` where each defines the corresponding single function, then the linker will include `a.o` and ignore `b.o`.

However, if `libA.a` included `ab.o` that defined both `a()` and `b()` then it will include `ab.o` in the link, satisfying the need for `a()`, and including the unused function `b()`.

As others have mentioned, there are linkers that are capable of splitting individual functions out of modules, and including only those that are actually used. In many cases, that is a safe thing to do. But it is usually safest to assume that your linker does not do that unless you have specific documentation.

Something else to be aware of is that most linkers make as few passes as they can through the files and libraries that are named on the command line, and build up their symbol table as they go. As a practical matter, this means that it is good practice to always specify libraries after all of the object modules on the link command line.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the linker.

eg. Microsoft Visual C++ has an option "Enable function level linking" so you can enable it manually.

(I assume they have a reason for not just enabling it all the time...maybe linking is slower or something)

Answer (score 1):

Usually (static) libraries are composed of objects created from source files. What linkers usually do is include the object if a function that is provided by that object is referenced. if your source file only contains one function than only that function will be brought in by the linker. There are more sophisticated linkers out there but most C based linkers still work like outlined. There are tools available that split C source that contain multiple functions into artificially smaller source files to make static linking more fine granular.

If you are using shared libraries then you don't impact you compiled size by using more or less of them. However your runtime size will include them.

Answer (score 1):

This [lecture](http://academicearth.org/lectures/naming) at Academic Earth gives a pretty good overview, linking is talked about near the later half of the talk, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the linker, but in general only functions that are actually called get included in the final executable. The linker works by looking up the function name in the library and then using the code associated with the name.

There are very few books on linkers, which is strange when you think how important they are. The text for a good one can be found [here](http://www.iecc.com/linker/).

Answer (score 0):

Without any optimization, yes, it'll be included. The linker, however, might be able to optimize out by statically analyzing the code and trying to remove unreachable code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the options passed to the linker, but typically the linker will leave out the object files in a library that are not referenced anywhere.

```
$ cat foo.c
int main(){}

$ gcc -static foo.c

$ size
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 452659    1928    6880  461467   70a9b a.out

# force linking of libz.a even though it isn't used
$ gcc -static foo.c -Wl,-whole-archive -lz -Wl,-no-whole-archive

$ size
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 517951    2180    6844  526975   80a7f a.out
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the linker and how the library was built. Usually libraries are a combination of object files (import libraries are a major exception to this).  Older linkers would pull things into the output file image at a granularity of the object files that were put into the library.  So if function `a()` and function `b()` were both in the same object file, they would both be in the output file - even if only one of the 2 functions were actually referenced.

This is a reason why you'll often see library-oriented projects with a policy of a single C function per source file.  That way each function is packaged in its own object file and linkers have no problem pulling in only what is referenced.

Note however that newer linkers (certainly newer Microsoft linkers) have the ability to pull in only parts of object files that are referenced, so there's less of a need today to enforce a one-function-per-source-file policy - though there are reasonable arguments that that should be done anyway for maintainability.